# Save the crawled images to current working directory

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, web-crawler

I crawled some images and it asks for the path of the folder where the images are to be saved. But, I want the images to be directly saved to the current working directory.

```
def save():
            if not config.get('images'):
                _alert('No images to save')
                return

            if _save_method.get() == 'img':
                dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True)
                _save_images(dirname)

        def _save_images(dirname):
            i=1
            if dirname and config.get('images'):
                for img in config['images']:
                    img_data = requests.get(img['url']).content
                    filename = str(i)
                    i=i+1
                    with open(filename +'.png','wb') as f:
                        f.write(img_data)
                _alert('Done')

     _scrape_btn = ttk.Button(
            _mainframe, text='Scrape!', command=save
        )
        _scrape_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)
```

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that something with that indentation would actually run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.` or get the current working directory with

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Can you guess what `cwd` stands for :)

Comment: (or just use `.`)

Comment: Ah yeah that works too lol. So used to cranking out os for everything. Forgot about the simple solution. That's the real answer here. Zen - simple is better than complex.